# Unable to save the exact timestamp from form

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp

I'm trying to save events into my table that contain `date_start` and `date_end` timestamps. From another PHP page, I get four inputs: two date inputs and two time inputs. I'm trying to insert these values but I keep getting the following value on inserting it:

> 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Here's my script:

```php
$rep=$bdd->query('SELECT * FROM association WHERE nom="'.$_SESSION['usertag'].'"');
$data=$rep->fetch();
$debut="\'".$_POST['date_start']." ".$_POST['time_start'].":00\'";
$fin="\'".$_POST['date_end']." ".$_POST['time_end'].":00\'";
$debut=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$fin=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$timestamp_debut =strtotime($debut);
$timestamp_fin = strtotime($fin);
$req=$bdd->query('INSERT into evenement values (NULL,'.$_POST['name'].','.$_POST['content'].',\''.$timestamp_debut.'\',\''.$timestamp_fin.'\','.$data['id'].')');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) outputs a Unix timestamp. If your database column type is [DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html), a Unix timestamp is not the correct format. You can just insert the formatted [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) string.

For example:

```
strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
```

> 1562117846

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

> 2019-07-02 21:36:40

For MySQL:

> MySQL recognizes DATETIME and TIMESTAMP values ... [a]s a string in either '**YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss**' or '**YY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss**' format. A "relaxed" syntax is permitted here, too: Any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts or time parts. For example, '2012-12-31 11:30:45', '2012^12^31 11+30+45', '2012/12/31 11*30*45', and '2012@12@31 11^30^45' are equivalent.
>
> [String and Numeric Literals in Date and Time Context](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html#date-and-time-string-numeric-literals)

---

However, it seems that you're using the current timestamp when you might want to use the values posted from your form. PHP's [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) uses "the current time if no timestamp is given".

If you want to use your posted values instead, you can indeed use `strtotime()` to convert them to Unix timestamps and then `date()` to format them.

```
$date = '2019-07-02';
$time = '15:28';

date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($date.' '.$time));
```

> 2019-07-02 15:28:00

Alternatively, I might recommend using PHP's [DateTime class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
$date = '2019-07-02';
$time = '15:28';

$datetime = new Datetime($date.' '.$time);
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

> 2019-07-02 15:28:00

Comment: thank you so much this answer explained a lot to me